# POST request with multipart/form-data content type to download a file

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

There's a webpage which includes a button inside the form. Clicking on that button makes a POST request and a CSV file gets downloaded.

I'm trying to automate the CSV downloading process using LWP::UserAgent.

I noticed from Chrome Developer Tools that the `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundary....`

Any idea how can I send the exact `Request Payload` which developer tools is showing?

I generally do the below for `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. But I have no idea how to submit multipart form data.

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->cookie_jar({ file => "cookie.txt", autosave => 1});


my $request = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $url);

#copy the form_data from chrome developer tools
my $form_data = 'key=val&key2=val2';

#the form_data is too big (and is in parts) in case of multipart content type

$request->content($form_data);
$request->header('Content-Type' => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
#I'll have to use `multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundary....`

#add some other headers like 'Origin', 'Host' and 'Referer' in similar manner
#...
#...

push @{ $ua->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';

my $response = $ua->request($request);

#Get the file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the entry on `POST` in [the documentation for `HTTP::Request::Common`](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/HTTP-Message-6.11/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm)

You can generate a `multipart/form-data` request (instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) by passing a pseudo header value of  `Content_Type => 'form-data'`

It would look like this

```
my $response = $ua->post(
    $url,
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    {
        ...;  # Hash of form key/value pairs
    }
);
```